# How do I connect to VMware from another PC?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am facing an issue with my VMware and Ubuntu PC. 
Scenario: I have a Windows 8.1 PC (IP: 192.168.1.10) and installed VM ware on this Window PC and installed Centos 7 on the VM ware (IP: 192.168.163.127). Also, I have another PC installed with Ubuntu 15.10 (IP: 192.168.1.12). I need to ping or connect to the Centos on the VM ware from my Ubuntu PC. I am using VMware workstation 12 Pro.
How do I can do this? Is this possible? Please, anybody, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the Networkadapter to bridged mode. At your virtual pc you need a IP like 192.168.1.... Then you have access to your virtual pc over your local network.

Answer (score 0):

By using NAT it is quite possible. For further information about how you can configure your NAT and Bridge please take a look at following links:
https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-D05850F8-E850-4086-A735-5C84C72D007C.html
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697
https://serverfault.com/questions/229860/vmware-networking-mode-nat-or-bridged

I hope it helps you.